# A non-existence example of a sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

In parametric statistical inference, a statistic $T$ of some variable $X$ (thought of as experimental or observational data) is *sufficient* for the parameter $\theta$ if is captures the essential information in the data $X$ about the parameter $\theta$ (there are several equivalent definitions for this). It is implicitly understood that the random variable $X$ has a probability distribution $f(x;\theta)$, where the parameter $\theta$ is of course unknown.

Related is the concept of a *minimal sufficient statistic*, which captures nothing more than the essential.

1. Is it true that any random variable $X$ as above *has* a sufficient statistic?
2. Suppose $X$ has a sufficient statistic $T$. Must it also have a minimal sufficient statistic?

I'd be glad to have either a concise proof or a simple counter-example for each of these two.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic. Wikipedia article on sufficient estimators: A case in which there is no minimal sufficient statistic was shown by Bahadur, 1954. However, under mild conditions, a minimal sufficient statistic does always exist. In particular, in Euclidean space, these conditions always hold if the random variables (associated with $P_{\theta }$) are all discrete or are all continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In a degenerate manner your sample $(X_1,...,X_n)$ is always a sufficient statistic from Fisher's information perspective. $T(X)$ is sufficient statistic for $\theta$ iff $\mathcal{I}_{\theta}(T(X))=\mathcal{I}_{\theta}(X_1,...,X_n)$.Thus for every parametric structure you can take the data points themselves as the sufficient statistic.
2. No. You have a minimial sufficient statistic iff your parametric distribution $f(X;\theta)$ can be factorized into $h(X)g(\theta; T(X))$, then the $T(X)$ is the minimal sufficient statistic or can be reduced to one. Moreover, it is pretty common to fail to satisfy this condition, e.g., Weibull distribution which density function is given by
   $$
   f(x;\theta)=\frac{\theta x^{\theta-1}}{\lambda^\theta}\exp\{-x^\theta/\lambda^\theta\}, x\ge 0,
   $$
   where $\theta > 0, \theta \neq 1$ is the unknown shape parameter, cannot be factorized w.r.t $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks @a-e. Is your answer to (2) not in contradiction to Marc's quote from Wikipedia, "_under mild conditions, a minimal sufficient statistic does always exist_"?

Comment: Don't know. I guess "mild" it's a relativistic statement. From my humble experience, although the existence of a minimal sufficient statistic is more common in parametric structures, yet a non-existence is not that rare phenomenon.

Comment: Alright. Thanks @a-e! As for (1), if I'm interested in non-trivial sufficient statistic, then are there necessary and/or sufficient conditions for their existence?

Comment: If by non-trivial you mean not $(X_1,...,X_n)$ then yes - the factorization theorem is iff statement. I.e., inter alia it provides a sufficient condition for the existence of a non-trivial sufficient statistic.

Comment: @V.Vancak Why the sample itself is a statistic? I thought a statistic must be a real-valued function of the sample.

Comment: @V.Vancak No. $h$ is a vector-valued function, not real-valued.

Comment: @TonyB Yes, sorry I didn't mean a scalar function, but a vector valued function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Anyway, a sufficient statistic is not necessarily a scalar function. The minimal sufficient stat is $h$ with the minimal $\dim$ of its Image. In some cases the minimal dimension is $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., you cannot compress the sample without losing information on the parameter(s).

Comment: In your example of Weibull distribution, taking h=1 gives you a factorization. The example is not showing the non-existence of minimal sufficient statistics.

Comment: @Sisi Thank you. I've added the restriction of $\theta \neq 0$ to avoid this special case that boils down to the exponential distribution.

Comment: Here for your example of Weibull distribution, $f(x; \theta)$ does factorize as $1 \cdot f(x; \theta)$. How do you show that the minimal sufficient statistics does not exist? I think your current argument does not go through.

Comment: Please see the definition of the criteria: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem
In your example, $1$ is independent of the sample, hence it is not a sufficient statistic (clearly not a minimal sufficient statistic).

Comment: Your argument for the Weibull distribution example still does not go through. If you don't like 1, one can always write $f(x; \theta) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \cdot [(1+x^2) f(x; \theta)] $, it is a dumb factorization, but it just shows a factorization exists and your argument does not lead to show the "non-existence of minimal sufficient statistics". Additional arguments are needed in order to conclude.